# ABP Boilerplate using SQL CE

Tags: sql-server-ce, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I have a simple ASP.NET application using EntityFramework and a SQL Server EF DB.

**The problem is that if I try to use SQL CE (Compact Edition), my application services throws an exception on the second call to the repository with the error:**

*ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection*.

All works successfully if I return to a SQL Express database.

Here the step and code I used:

Modification to the client application App.config file (I report only changes):

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" .../>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" connectionString="Data Source=C:\temp\Deeds.sdf" />**
  </connectionStrings>
  ...
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  ...
</configuration>
```

They I had to set the isolation level of the UOW:

```
public class DeedsWinFormEFModule : AbpModule {

    public override void PreInitialize() {
        Configuration.UnitOfWork.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
    }

    public override void Initialize() {
        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}
```

But in my ApplicationService this method fails on the second DB query

```
public class DeedImmobileAppService
    : DeedsAppServiceBase, IDeedImmobileAppService {

    protected readonly IRepository<CfgBase100Repo> _cfgBase100Repo;
    protected readonly IRepository<CfgCasa> _cfgCasaRepo;

...

    public async Task<IReadOnlyList<DeedEntryDto>> CalculateValuesForEntries(UpdateDefaultEntriesRequest input) {
        var tipoCasa = await _cfgCasaRepo.FirstOrDefaultAsync(input.HouseTypeId);
        var base100 = await _cfgBase100Repo.FirstOrDefaultAsync(cfg => (cfg.MinDeedRange <= input.DeedValue) && (input.DeedValue < cfg.MaxDeedRange));
        ...
        return list;
    }
}
```

The second call to the repository **always** fails (`var tipoCasa = ...`):

```
    var base100 = await _cfgBase100Repo.FirstOrDefaultAsync(cfg => (cfg.MinDeedRange <= input.DeedValue) && (input.DeedValue < cfg.MaxDeedRange));
    var tipoCasa = await _cfgCasaRepo.FirstOrDefaultAsync(input.HouseTypeId);
```

I also tried to invert the lines. In this case `var base100 =` fails:

```
    var tipoCasa = await _cfgCasaRepo.FirstOrDefaultAsync(input.HouseTypeId);
    var base100 = await _cfgBase100Repo.FirstOrDefaultAsync(cfg => (cfg.MinDeedRange <= input.DeedValue) && (input.DeedValue < cfg.MaxDeedRange));
```

The error I receive is:

```
Inner Exception 1:
EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is Closed.
```

**Here the stack trace:**

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException   HResult=0x80131604
>   Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry
>   tme)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry
>   tme)    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)    at
>   GPSoftware.Deeds.WinForm.Program.Main() in
>   C:\WA\GPse\NotuleNotai\Notule\Deeds.WinForm\Program.cs:line 34

**Inner Exception 1:**

> EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the
>   command definition. See the inner exception for details.

**Inner Exception 2:**

> InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires an open and
>   available Connection. The connection's current state is Closed.

Comment: Try marking `CalculateValuesForEntries` as `virtual`.

Comment: Tried but it doesn't work. The solution is to avoid transactions with SQL CE and EF, as EF doesn't support SQL CE transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it is the right solution, but I solved the issue by **marking the UOW not transactional**:

```
[DependsOn(
    typeof(DeedsDataModule),
    typeof(DeedsApplicationModule))]
public class DeedsWinFormEFModule : AbpModule {

    public override void PreInitialize() {
        // Configuration.UnitOfWork.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;  // <= this is not needed!
        Configuration.UnitOfWork.IsTransactional = false; // <= solution!
    }

    public override void Initialize() {
        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is the correct solution: EF doesn't support SQL CE transactions because *TransactionScope* can cause escalation to a distributed transaction when using SQL CE with Code First and SQL CE does not support distributed transactions.